# the correct usage of "feel appropriate" phrase

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> People should not be forced to retire, and they should be allowed to continue working as they feel appropriate.

I want to say as they feel it is OK. Is this a correct usage of the word?

Comment: I would use *as they feel **is** appropriate*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to say "...feel is appropriate".

When you say "They feel..." the adjective is usually one that gives an emotion. For example "they feel happy".  It is not the people who feel appropriate. The people feel that the time for working is appropriate. So the shortened form would be

> People should work for as long as they feel is appropriate.

Comment: I wonder what the subject of the "is" is. If the subject is implied/omitted, is there a way to rephrase that sentence with the subject? Also I wonder why people say "They should handle the problem as they see fit" but "They should handle the problem as they feel is appropriate".